# How to generate a resolv.conf from every DHCP lease on Mac?

Tags: macos, dhcp, dnsmasq

I just want to use a generated resolv.conf file from DHCP lease other than system's /etc/resolv.conf, how can I make a script that every time when DHCP lease then generate a resolv.conf?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very hard to understand, but I'll give it a shot...

`/etc/resolv.conf` is not canonical on OS X. If you want to change the system DNS settings then you need to use the System Configuration framework (from code), or `networksetup` or `scutil` (from the command line).  There's an article about using `scutil` [here](http://www.afp548.com/article.php?story=20050703052052393).

Comment: I understand that `/etc/resolv.conf` is not canonical, but it is still used if you use `host` or `nslookup`, AFAICT. I have found that I can move my laptop from one network to another and the `/etc/resolv.conf` is not updated, so `host` no longer works. It would be nice if I could force it to regenerate.

Comment: In that case, this is a bug, one which I've never seen.  I'd suggest reporting it.  You might find ControlPlane (http://www.controlplaneapp.com/) useful as a workaround; you can pretty easily transform the usual output from `scutil --dns` into an `/etc/resolv.conf`.